# Why my mom and I can't play together, but not on a mini game server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My mom and I want to get on the same server but not on a mini game server.

How can we get on the same server just the two of us and nobody else? So I can teach her on computer first and then xbox so how do we get on the same server on computer.

Comment: Have you set up a Minecraft server already?

Comment: Xbox would probably be much easier to do. Why do you not want to go for the easy way first?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are both playing on the PC instance of the game and running the same version of Minecraft, right?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to host a game on your computer in order to play together with your mom. There are two ways of going about this:

1. (easier) You can open any of your single-player games, pause the game, and click "Open to LAN." This will allow people on your local network to join your world. You can choose whether new players will start in Survival or Creative, as well as choose to enable/disable cheats. When you exit your world, the world is closed to LAN again, and players cannot connect to it. Anyone still in it will be kicked automatically. If you do this option, you must re-open it to LAN every time you load your save file when you want someone to connect.
2. (more difficult) You can start your own server. This is still pretty secure, as you need the server's unique IP in order to connect to it. Thus, you can create your own server (which is hosted on your computer), give your mom the IP, and both of you can play on that together. I don't have any experience creating servers, I tried making one, and it's a fairly difficult process without a good guide.

If it's just you and your mom playing, I'd say go option 1. It's much easier to start a single-player match and open it up to LAN every time you want to play together. Hope this helped.